# I want to know a way to plot a bar graph using plotly for the following code

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, bar-chart

[image: Code related to the question and the result for the code I wrote]

Can anyone help me to show a way to plot bar graphs for the output type of the code I wrote. Thank you

Comment: Please include all relevant code as text in your question, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Please copy-paste the error as well as the code. This can help people read the code and error better. This can also let people run the code and it can lead to better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is just plot the data shown in the output it would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
#Imports

fig = px.bar(x=['SQL','Javascript', 'CSS', 'C#'], y=[1613,1420,1356,1352], title="Bar graph of proficient languages")
#The x can be a list of the dictionary keys
#The y can be a list of the dictionary values
print(fig.show())
```

An alternative to this to make it in one index would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
#imports

df = pd.DataFrame({'SQL':1613,'Javascript':1420, 'CSS':1356,'C#':1352}, index=[0])
#put in dictionary values
fig = px.bar(data_frame=df)
#plots graph
fig.show()
#shows graph
```

I have very limited information at the time of answering, so this question might not be the best answer.